# 16x32 led dot matrix

Tags: matrix, led

I have 16x32 led dot matrix(has 3 colors red,green, yellow) with Ethernet port. Unfortunately today I send wrong code combination and my led reset itself so does not accept manufacture codes. Is it possible to configure this device? if yes how I can do?

please look the below link for more information my dot matrix.

[dot matrix](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9n61x4i6ho3mggd/AAB6wRNV1V0MyPfFM233NDlva?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

You could open the case and look for a "port" ex. A serial 6 pin header or something like that. Then you could upload the fimware again.

Do you have and specific name of that Matix?

Comment: I will update my question and add more detail about dot matrix